# array formation in php

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to form the array, like below. how can i form the below one, in foreach:

```
{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "totalRecords": 3,
  "errorMessage": "",
  "organizations": [
    {
      "organizationId": 1
    },
    {
      "organizationId": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

My code:

```
$orgArray =  array();
foreach($organizationInterface as $organization){
    $orgArray[] = array(
        'organizationId' => $organization->getId()
    );
}
```

The above present code, i would like to change something like this:

```
 foreach($organizationInterface as $organization){
    $orgArr['organizationId'] = $organization->getId();
 }
```

Comment: Your first code snippet looks good, whats wrong with it?

Comment: yes, nothing seems wrong in the  first code

Comment: just follow the brackets/bracing - each time you go "down" a level, it's a new array/object.

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand you want something like this:

```
    foreach($organizationInterface as $organization){
        $orgArr['organizationId'][] = $organization->getId();
    }
```

You can't have more than one value on a single array key, which is what you want to do there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$jsonString = '{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "totalRecords": 3,
    "errorMessage": "",
    "organizations": [
       {
         "organizationId": 1
       },
       {
         "organizationId": 2
       }
     ]
}';

$jsonObj = json_decode($jsonString);
echo 'Status: ' . $jsonObj->status;
foreach($jsonObj->organizations as $org) { 
   echo 'Organization ID: ' . $org->organizationId;
}
```